# How do I check if my Python Discord bot has the necessary permissions?

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a utility bot to help with logging messages and help migrating channels from one server to another. I needed to check if it has the necessary permissions to perform its commands, but the following code does not work (I use `@client.event` and don't wish to use `@bot.command`) Here's my permission checking code:

```
if not client.user.server_permissions.text.read_messages: await send_message(message.channel,"Please give me permission to read messages!")

if not client.user.server_permissions.text.manage_messages: await send_message(message.channel, "Please give me permission to manage messages!")

if not client.user.server_permissions.text.read_message_history: await send_message(message.channel, "Please give me permission to read message history!")

if not client.user.server_permissions.text.attach_files: await send_message(message.channel, "Please give me permission to attach files!")
```

This above does not work, I get the following error when I test it with the appropriate conditions:

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'server_permissions'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please expand on *"does not work"*. Also consider following [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) when writing code, particularly when you intend to share it.

Comment: If you could share your error code with us, it would give us more context.

Comment: Edited my post, made the suggested changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User` objects don't have server permissions, `Member` objects do.  (Because a `User` can be a `Member` of multiple servers, with different permissions in each)  To get the `Member` object representing your bot on a particular server, use `Server.me`.  So for all of your examples, change

```
client.user.server_permissions
```

to

```
message.channel.server.me.server_permissions
```

Answer (score 4):

When using the Python Rewrite (v1.0), the naming scheme has changed from `server` to `guild`. This changes the correct code to:

`message.channel.guild.me.guild_permissions`

(the difference between `User` and `Member` as shown by @patrick-haugh is still correct)

Comment: How do I check if the bot has permission in a specific channel of that guild?

Comment: Channel permissions are handled as overwrites. Therefore you need to request the so called `overwrite` for each role your bot owns and apply that overwrite onto the guild permissions in the correct order (they can stack on each other).

This can be achieved by using the `channel.overwrites_for(obj)` method.

I can't post code in a simple comment, but maybe making this an own question could make sense

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I understood the concept

Comment: Here's a gist for an example implementation
https://gist.github.com/Mayerch1/187fca7ab0d03a9f0d4f98da56875de5