# Is it possible to link the Discord server's name with its invite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, discord, discord.py

I have a list that stores dictionaries of the names of the servers my bot is in.
The following is within a for loop, so `server_name` is different for each server the bot is in:

```python
servers = [{"Name": server_name},{"Name": server_name}]
```

I also have a piece of code that creates an invite for each server (which is also in a for loop) and appends the invites to a list.

When I `print()` out the invites list, I get this:

```python
[<Invite code='XXX' guild=<Guild id=XXX name='XXX' shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=X> online=X members=X>]
```

I wanna know if there is a way to relate the server's invite to the server's name, so I can have one dictionary with the name and another with all the servers' invites.

```python
for guild in bot.guilds:
    {"Name": name}
    {"Invite": invite of that server}
```

I tried to go through every `guild`'s `name` in my list with the loop above, but I have no idea how to grab the `invite of that server`.

Comment: Use JSON. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72191716/discord-py-add-different-str-object-to-different-users. It's built-in, so you don't have to install it.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder the post you linked further confused me. Could you explain what you mean some more?

Comment: You have many ways to do so. It's all your creativity. Try understanding JSON's format and how to use/implement it. You can put the objects as-is (the list) with their server invites in the same order in a JSON, but as it depends on the order that can be easily distorted, I suggest you restructure your code. Create a JSON object/file and put all the details of the servers (remove the list; for a server: its name, invite and whatever details of it you want as its properties) in it. You don't need dictionaries. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-data-types/.

Comment: TBH, I've not used JSON in Python much either. I just installed it once, so I may not be the best person to explain/suggest this. Seen and heard of JSON a lot, and it would be sensible to store it as one. Try your best, and if you don't get how to implement it, I'll try to answer.

Comment: Ill give it a shot but ill probably fail. I originally wanted to see if anyone knew a method to grab the invite of a server by knowing its name with discord.py but i dont think there is a way

Comment: Wait- I guess I misunderstood your question. Is your whole question about getting the invite of a server by its name?

Comment: Also, no. There is not only one invite to a server; there can be many; you can create many invites, mostly infinity; check it, though. But, I guess there's a permission that allows you to create invites. Check if you have that permission. You will most probably have it. If you don't, while generating the invite for your bot (not any server) on the Discord Developer page, check that permission.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder what i did to counter this and take counter with a grain of salt is i loop through all the guilds and make my bot create an invite then append that invite to a list but i just dont know how to relate the invites of that list with the names of the guilds the invites are from

Comment: Ok, I'll try to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Using JSON, you can store the details of each server in separate dictionaries and put them all in a JSON object/string.

For example, you can put the details in a [nested-dictionary](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-nested-dictionary/) (a dictionary in a dictionary) like this:

```py
{
    guild.name: 
        {
            "name": server_name,
            "invite": server_invite,
            "any other details (eg: its owner)": guild.owner
        }
}
```

And then convert it to JSON using [`json.dumps()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-dumps-in-python/), so you can save and load it again if you want.

So, your code would be something like:

```py
json_servers_info = "{}" #Create an empty JSON object/string. Everything will be stored in this. 

for guild in bot.guilds:
    if discord.Permissions.create_instant_invite in guild.me.guild_permissions:
    #Check if your bot has permission to create invites on the server.
    #Not sure if this is the way to check it.
        server_name = guild.name #Getting the guild's name
        server_invite = channel.create_invite(max_age=0, max_uses=0)
        #Creating an invite to the server from the channel in which the message is sent

        this_servers_info = {guild.name: {
            "name": server_name,
            "invite": server_invite,
            "any other details (eg: its owner)": guild.owner
        }}
        #Creating the nested-dictionary

        servers_info = json.loads(json_servers_info) #Converting the JSON into a dictionary
        servers_info.update(this_servers_info) #Appending the nested-dictionary to the empty one
        json_servers_info = json.dumps(servers_info) #Converting the nested-dictionary back into a JSON
```

You can use `if guild.me.guild_permissions.create_instant_invite:` instead of the second line if it doesn't work. See [How do I check if my Python Discord bot has the necessary permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279986/how-do-i-check-if-my-python-discord-bot-has-the-necessary-permissions).
The parameters `max_age` and `max_uses` set when it will expire and how many times the invite can be used. If both they're set to `0`, the invite will never expire and can be used infinity times.

To get the information of a particular server, you would use [`json.loads()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) and get the details of the server by indexing the nested-dictionary:

```py
servers_info = json.loads(json_servers_info) #Convert the JSON into a dictionary
requested_info = servers_info[str(message.guild)] #Index the dictionary to get the server's details
```

I've made a Discord [Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html) with 2 commands, one to log the servers' information and another to show the info of the server one is in:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import json
#Imports

intent = discord.Intents()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="", description="", intents=intent)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot's online!")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):

    json_servers_info = "{}"

    content = message.content #The message's content
    channel = message.channel #The channel in which the message is sent
    
    if "log server information" in content:
        await channel.send("Logging...")
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            if discord.Permissions.create_instant_invite in guild.me.guild_permissions:
                server_name = guild.name
                server_invite = channel.create_invite(max_age=0, max_uses=0)
                this_servers_info = {guild.name: {
                    "name": server_name,
                    "invite": server_invite,
                    "any other details (eg: its owner)": guild.owner
                }}
                servers_info = json.loads(json_servers_info)
                servers_info.update(this_servers_info)
                json_servers_info = json.dumps(servers_info)
        await channel.send("Logged!")
    
    elif "show this servers info" in content:
        servers_info = json.loads(json_servers_info)
        requested_info = servers_info[str(message.guild)]
        await channel.send(requested_info)
```

I have **not** tested this. This is just an example of when and where to use the code and how. Also, note that when one uses the "log server information" command, the details of all servers the bot is in will be logged, not just of the one in which the message (command) is sent.